# How do you know how many cointegrating factors there are?

Tags: time-series, cointegration

I am new to the concept of cointegration so I apologize ahead of time if this is basic. I have read that ... "When there is a single long run relationship, the ARDL procedure can distinguish between dependent and explanatory variables." How do you know how many cointegrating relationships there are.

I know of test for cointegration, but they show if it exist or not. Not if there is one or many.

Comment: More precisely, you mean "...how many linearly independent cointegrating relationships are there?" Johansen's eigenvalue and trace tests provide sequential procedures for testing cointegration rank (something residual-based tests, like Engel-Granger, cannot do).

Comment: thanks. I will be doing the ardl type of cointegration not Johansen. Does it matter for this issue. Can you do the test you mention and then do cointegration in ARDL (bound testing).